# Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the enabled property of the OLEObject class

Tags: excel, vba

I got the above error message when I set `combobox2.enable = True` when there's a change in combobox1.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

   If ComboBox1.Value = "One Session" Then
      ComboBox2.Enabled = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Can someone please tell me what's went wrong? Thanks

Comment: I tried to simulate this problem, however it works perfectly fine for me. Is there some extra dependancy for ComboBox2 in your application (is it part of a hidden/disabled Frame or Form?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the names of each combobox are ComboBox1 and ComboBox2. If you renamed them, it could give errors such as this.

Plus if you've got combobox2 disabled (Enabled=false) for some reason, this is what you need, however if you're trying to have excel set the focus onto ComboBox2, use `ComboBox2.SetFocus`

Comment: If you have wrong name you would rather get error `424- Object require`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the combobox is in your worksheet.

There are two main reasons for getting this error.

1. ActiveX Controls are disabled. You may want to see [THIS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/enable-or-disable-activex-controls-in-office-documents-HA010031067.aspx) OR
2. Your worksheet is protected. If your worksheet is protected then you have two ways to handle it

**Way 1**

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "YOUR PASSWORD"
    If ComboBox1.Value = "One Session" Then
       ComboBox2.Enabled = True
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect "YOUR PASSWORD"
End Sub
```

OR

**Way 2**

This uses `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` which allows you to make changes to the sheet only using macros

```
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="YOUR PASSWORD", _
DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, _
Scenarios:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

I keep running into this issue, and my resolution is slightly different from the prior two answers.  In my case, the **object** is locked, as well as the worksheet.  My resolution is to unprotect the worksheet, select the object causing the error, go into its properties, and uncheck "Locked".  Then reprotect the worksheet and save.